# Resource path of Apache Camel inside war file

Tags: war, apache-camel

I trying to deploy a Apache Camel application inside a war file. Webapp structure is as follows:

```
webapp
..WEB-INF
...folder1
....event.xsl
```

The below code is not working and I am getting error 'Cannot find resource in classpath'

```
    <route>
        <from uri="seda:trade2confirmation" />
        <to uri="xslt:/WEB-INF/folder1/event.xsl" />
        <to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
    </route>
```

What is the correct way to access event.xsl file?

Answer (score 1):

What web container do you use? And what Camel version?

And have you tried without the leading / slash.

```
<to uri="xslt:WEB-INF/folder1/event.xsl" />
```

Comment: I am using Jetty 6.1.26 and Camel 2.10.

Comment: Can you upgrade Camel to latest 2.9.x release.